# jest-mock-extended - call mock with object input [Typescript]

Tags: typescript, jestjs, equality, ts-jest, jest-mock-extended

I'm using [jest-mock-extended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-extended) in my tests.

I would like to test the following code:

```
class A {

  constructor(private b: B){}

  public test(x: string): string {

    const res1 = this.b.compose({
      name: x + '_foo'
    })

    const res2 = this.b.compose({
      name: x + '_bar'
    })
  }

  return res1 + '_' + res2
}
```

And my test:

```
test(() => {
  const bMock: MockProxy<B> = mock<B>()
  const a: A = new A(bMock)
  
  bMock.compose.calledWith({
                x: 'yoyo_foo'
            }).mockReturnValueOnce(x + '_once')

  bMock.compose.calledWith({
                x: 'yoyo_bar'
            }).mockReturnValueOnce(x + '_twice')
  //ACT
  const result = a.test('yoyo')

  //ASSERT
  expect(result).toBe('yoyo_foo_once_yoyo_bar_twice)
})
```

But since the `calledWith` function is using [referential equality](https://dmitripavlutin.com/how-to-compare-objects-in-javascript/#1-referential-equality) it doesn't work, the `compose` function of the mocked object returns `undefined`.
Is there a way to make it work? Maybe to enforce a [shallow equality](https://dmitripavlutin.com/how-to-compare-objects-in-javascript/#3-shallow-equality)?
I would like to be able to use the `calledWith` function with an object, is there a way?
Is there another way to mock the compose function according to its input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `containsValue('value')` matcher from [jest-mock-extended](https://github.com/marchaos/jest-mock-extended)

in `eg.ts` file

```
export interface B {
    compose(obj): string
}

export class A {
    constructor(private b: B) {}

    public test(x: string): string {
        const res1 = this.b.compose({
            name: x + "_foo"
        })

        const res2 = this.b.compose({
            name: x + "_bar"
        })
        return res1 + "_" + res2
    }
}
```

in `eg.test.ts` file

```
// libs
import { test, expect } from "@jest/globals"
import { mock, MockProxy, objectContainsValue } from "jest-mock-extended"

import { A, B } from "./eg"

test("test", () => {
    const bMock: MockProxy<B> = mock<B>()
    const a: A = new A(bMock)

    bMock.compose
        .calledWith(objectContainsValue("yoyo_foo"))
        .mockReturnValueOnce("yoyo_foo" + "_once")

    bMock.compose
        .calledWith(objectContainsValue("yoyo_bar"))
        .mockReturnValueOnce("yoyo_bar" + "_twice")
    //ACT
    const result = a.test("yoyo")

    //ASSERT
    expect(result).toBe("yoyo_foo_once_yoyo_bar_twice")
})
```